# Calculating heartbeats per minute from a .wav file

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, deep-learning, signal-processing

I am working on a machine learning project relating to heart-Arrhythmia's. 
I want to be able to calculate heart beats per minute from a 30 second wav file as input. I am creating a mel-spectrogram and normal spectrogram from the heart-sounds. My goal is to be able to return the total number of beats per minute from the 30 second clip.

Here are some examples of the spectrograms and mel-spectrograms that I generate:

[image]

[image]

I was thinking that if I could write a model to count the number of "peaks" in the program then I could simply multiply that number by 2 (30 seconds * 2 = 1 min) to get the beats per minute (BPM).

I found this source while researching and while its not directly related to heartbeat sounds it may come in handy:
https://nlml.github.io/neural-networks/detecting-bpm-neural-networks/

I need some advice on how to solve this problem, what kind of network I should use, and some sample code to get me started.

Comment: Have you considered a FFT to determine periodicity of the amplitude (electric potential)?

Comment: @AdamO No I haven't. I don't really know much about FFT or how to use it. Do you recommend any resources/sites where I could gain the knowledge to solve my problem?